# Convertir en un link o boton al panel

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, bootstrap

Amigos buenas tardes, estoy tratando de hacer que un `panel` me redireccione a una página, el problema es como hago que todo el `panel` se active cuando se paso el mouse y al hacer clic me redireccione a una página.

Como si fuera un boton, al pasar el mouse se active con un color más suave y al dar clic lleve a una página en específico llevando los valores de ese `panel` "nro de habitación".

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lZN37f5QGtY3VHgisS14W3ExzMWZxybE1SJSEsQp9S+oqd12jhcu+A56Ebc1zFSJ" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Paneles</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-12" style="padding-bottom: 10px;">
                    <div class="card" style="background-color: #218838;">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-6">
                                <h3 class="text-center font_color">108</h3>
                                <h6 class="text-center font_color">Triple</h6>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-6">
                                <i class="fa fa-bed font_color" aria-hidden="true" style="font-size: 4em; "></i>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-12">
                                                                <strong><center>Libre</center></strong>
                                                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-12" style="padding-bottom: 10px;">
                    <div class="card" style="background-color: #c82333;">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-6">
                                <h3 class="text-center font_color">103</h3>
                                <h6 class="text-center font_color">Doble</h6>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-6">
                                <i class="fa fa-bed font_color" aria-hidden="true" style="font-size: 4em; "></i>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-12">
                                                                <strong><center>Ocupado</center></strong>
                                                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                 </div>
                </div>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

No hay problema si se hace con javascript o jquery lo importante es que se pueda convertir en un link.

Gracias por su apoyo!

Answer (score 3):

Podrias utilizar la etiqueta `<a>` de siempre, utilizando un `div`, `section` o cualquier contenedor que quieras y simplemente darle un poco de css cuando ocurra un `hover` (Mouse sobre el panel) de la siguiente forma:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
    <style type="text/css" media="screen">
        section {
            background: #F60;
            color: #FFF;
            width: 400px;
            height: 200px;
        }
        section:hover {
            background: #CCC;
        }
        .transicion {
            transition: all ease-in-out 1s;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="https://www.google.com">
        <section class='transicion'>
            <span>Aqui mi contenido</span>
        </section>
    </a>
</body>
</html>
```

Y con JQuery seria algo asi:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <style type="text/css" media="screen">
        section {
            background: #F60;
            color: #FFF;
            width: 400px;
            height: 200px;
        }
        section:hover {
            background: #CCC;
        }
        .transicion {
            transition: all ease-in-out 1s;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <section id='myContent'>
        <span>mi Contenido</span>
    </section>

    <script>
        $('#myContent').click(function(e){
            window.location.href = 'https://www.google.com';
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Ahora bien veo que tambien necesitas obtener el número de habitación, ésto podrias hacerlo con unas ligeras modificaciones, utilizaré el ejemplo de `click` que te mostré anteriormente:

```
$('.card').click(function(e){ // El click se verifica por la clase para que funcione en todos tus paneles
    var habitacion = $(this).find('h3').text(); // En este caso vi que el numero de habitacion estaba en un h3 es por eso que hago referencia a éste
    alert('Esta es la habitacion: ' + habitacion);
    // window.location.href = 'https://www.google.com';
    // Aqui redireccionas ya sea con metodo POST, GET o cualquier forma que utilices
});
```

Asi obtienes el número de habitación y bueno podrias combinar la redireccion con la forma de obtener la habitación según como quieres enviar el datos.

Te dejo tu código modificado:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lZN37f5QGtY3VHgisS14W3ExzMWZxybE1SJSEsQp9S+oqd12jhcu+A56Ebc1zFSJ" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Paneles</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-12" style="padding-bottom: 10px;">

                    <div class="card" style="background-color: #218838;">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-6">
                                <h3 class="text-center font_color">108</h3>
                                <h6 class="text-center font_color">Triple</h6>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-6">
                                <i class="fa fa-bed font_color" aria-hidden="true" style="font-size: 4em; "></i>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-12">
                                                                <strong><center>Libre</center></strong>
                                                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>

    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-12" style="padding-bottom: 10px;">
                    <div class="card" style="background-color: #c82333;">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-6">
                                <h3 class="text-center font_color">103</h3>
                                <h6 class="text-center font_color">Doble</h6>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-6">
                                <i class="fa fa-bed font_color" aria-hidden="true" style="font-size: 4em; "></i>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-12">
                                                                <strong><center>Ocupado</center></strong>
                                                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                 </div>
                </div>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script>
    $('.card').click(function(e){
        var habitacion = $(this).find('h3').text(); // En este caso vi que el numero de habitacion estaba en un h3 es por eso que hago referencia a éste
        alert('Esta es la habitacion: ' + habitacion);
        // window.location.href = 'https://www.google.com';
    });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Espero te sirva. Saludos ;)